# How to extract certain rows from spark dataframe to create another spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

In pandas dataframe `df`, one can extract a subset of rows and store it in another pandas data frame.  For example, `df1 = df[10:20]`. Can we do something similar in spark dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `row_number`, it will add increasing row number column. The data will be sorted by column used in `.orderBy` clause. Then you can just select needed rows.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window 
 val new_df = df.withColumn("id",row_number.over(Window.orderBy('someColumnFromDf))).where('id <= 20 and 'id >= 10)
```

Comment: Be extra careful. The window specification has got no `partitionBy`. If you've got more rows than a single executor can handle, it will OOME.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're at Spark, we're considering large datasets for which Pandas (and Python) are still catching up. I'm trying to stress out that the reason you may've considered PySpark as a better fit for your data processing problem is exactly the amount of data - to large for pandas to handle nicely.

With that said, you simply cannot think about the huge dataset as something to "rank" as no computer could handle it (either because lack of RAM or time).

In order to answer your question:

> one can extract a subset of rows and store it in another pandas data frame.

think of `filter` or `where` that you use to filter out rows you don't want to include in a result dataset.

That could be as follows (using Scala API):

```
val cdf: DataFrame = ...
val result: DataFrame = cdf.where("here comes your filter expression")
```

Use `result` data frame however you wish. That's what you wanted to work with and is now available. That's a sort of "Spark way".

Comment: Good point. Huge dataframes are the reason why one might be considering spark dataframe. I am trying to learn spark dataframe from what I know from Pandas. The current solution meets my requirements but it is not going to help me if/when my spark dataframe  gets huge. Is there a function in pyspark that will allow me to extract a window of size 'k' from spark dataframe and move the window 1 step forward at a time, until all 'n' rows in the spark dataframe has been used?  k<<n. for example, n = 40000, and k = 100

Comment: Please ask a separate question so it's more visible. We all are here to learn from each other :) If you think my answer answers your question better, you can mark it as accepted (even though you've already marked one as such). Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

@chlebek since your answer works for me. I corrected a typo and post here as an answer.

```
    b = cdf.withColumn("id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("INTERVAL_END_DATETIME")))
    b = b.where(b.id >= 10)
    b = b.where(b.id <= 20)
```